# JavaScript- JSON data parsing issue (Number is getting rounded to some other number)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to JavaScript and facing a problem.

I have one API to consume which returns response as 
`"data":[{name: 'fileName.png', id: 1575890170351016000 }]` for a given GET request. Later I use this **id** field for some other operations.

**Issue-** When i am hitting the API using curl I am receiving the id value as- **1575890170351016059** but If I try getting it via my script I am getting it as - **1575890170351016000**. How can I fix this problem. I want it be the same number which I get in response.

I am using **node-fetch** library to execute my get request. I read about the precision issue while dealing with a number in java script but don't know where exactly this library is converting the response to json object.

Comment: `If I try getting it via my script` What do you mean exactly? How are you accessing this value?

Comment: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` yields 9.007199254740991E+15 which is somewhat smaller than your number 1.575890170351016059E+18. This is why the last 3 digits are lost.

Comment: That number is too big, but you can simply keep it as string instead. Change the API accordingly, and JS will keep the string when parsing the JSON into an object.

Comment: (also note that there's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is text that looks very similar or exactly like JS object literals)

Comment: Thanks all. Its a third party API so I can't change the response. Is there any other way by which I can manage this?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. If you turn it into valid JSON it [seems to work fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/z8ybcrvf/)

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Developer Console I tried creating a variable with the number 1575890170351016059. I see it actually gets set to 1575890170351016000. So JavaScript itself does not like numbers of that size and actually rounds it down!

Asim's response is correct assuming you can get the API to send the object with ID as string. However when you call JSON.parse (or the node-fetch calls the function JSON.parse on the string) you end up with the rounding error!

I tried typing this object into Chrome console and received the same "bug":

```
[{name: 'fileName.png', id: 1575890170351016123 }]
```

When I examined the object the rounding occurs because the number is too big. Since  you can't change their API you can use JSON-BigInt, found here

https://github.com/sidorares/json-bigint

See example on the front page.

All that's required then is to see if you can use Node-Fetch to just get the string (not the object) and then JSON.parse it yourself with json-bigint

Answer (score -3):

Please try to use string for id, as number doesn't take that much value.

while sending the response.

```
 "data": :[{name: 'fileName.png', id: '1575890170351016059' }]
```

It will resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.  That's a third party API . I can't change the response.  Any other way?

Comment: when you convert response json to object then use string for that particular key value.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. You can't have `name` or `'` or `id`